# Twig template for search results page

Tags: theming, 8, search

I'm attempting to create a custom template for the search page located at

```
127.0.0.1/search/node
```

I've created a template called search-result.html.twig in my theme/templates folder which allows me to modify each search result but I'd like to actually modify the buttons and text fields at the top of the search page.

Is there a specific template that affects the search button and fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a search form template?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/211164/how-to-create-a-search-form-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I'd like to actually modify the buttons and text fields at the top
>   of the search page.

They do not have templates by default, because they are forms. You could create a twig template for the search form by follow this tutorial: [How to manipulate forms in Drupal 8](http://www.foreach.be/blog/how-manipulate-forms-drupal-8)

But in my opinion, it is easier to use hook_form_alter on your **.theme** file and add the classes here.

This is how, the drupal default theme, Bartik changes the search button to a magnifying glass icon by adding a custom class to the submit button in **bartik.theme**

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter() to add classes to the search form.
 */
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, ['search_block_form', 'search_form'])) {
    $key = ($form_id == 'search_block_form') ? 'actions' : 'basic';
    if (!isset($form[$key]['submit']['#attributes'])) {
      $form[$key]['submit']['#attributes'] = new Attribute();
    }
    $form[$key]['submit']['#attributes']->addClass('search-form__submit');
  }
}
```

[image]

You can use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and use `dpm($form)` to see what's inside the $form array.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter() to add classes to the search form.
 */
function bartik_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (in_array($form_id, ['search_block_form', 'search_form'])) {
    $key = ($form_id == 'search_block_form') ? 'actions' : 'basic';
        drupal_set_message(dpm($form));
  }
}
```

Make sure you don't have the search block on the search page, other wise it will print the array for both forms and might confuse you which one is which.

Comment: This is slick! However, I am not sure why do you need to restart Apache. Can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @AjitS thx for pointing that out, updated answer, that's just a habit of mine from dealing with the settings.php file, no need for that here.

Comment: No problem :) I was under an impression that Twig has something to do at server level that I am not aware of. Good to know it doesn't. Btw, I only restart Apache when I add a new host/change existing host, or make any changes to .htaccess file. The changes in settings.php file should be picked up directly without the server restart.

Comment: Thank you! The reason why I'd like to change the buttons using the templates instead of just CSS is because I'd like to wrap them in divs using foundation.

Comment: @Matt updated my answer since after doing some research my original answer didn't really answer your Q.